# Why When I replace the begin() with end() the output = 0 not 4?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, data-structures

When I dereference `std::begin()` in the following code, it correctly shows the value of the first element in the vector:

```
 vector<int> v = { 3, 1, 4 };
 auto vi = begin(a);
 cout << *vi << '\n'; // outputs 3
```

However, when I use `std::end()`, I don't reliably get the last value in the vector. Why is that?

```
 vector<int> v = { 3, 1, 4 };
 auto vi = end(v);
 cout << *vi << '\n';  // Expected 4, but got 0
```

Comment: `end(.)` does not point to the last element, but to the fictive next one. Deferencing it is UB

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour on deferencing the iterator returned by `std::end(v)` is *undefined*. Your getting `0` back is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour and is therefore by no means guaranteed. Informally you can think of it as being a pointer to one element beyond the end of the container.

Dereferencing `std::begin(v)` is fine (so long as the container is not empty), as that's the first element in the container.

Comment: `Dereferencing std::begin(v) is fine, as that's the first element in the container.` might be a bit misleading. It is true for the given case, but `std::begin(v)` would be equal to `std::end(v)` if the list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`std::end(v)` denotes the end of a container.

As already mentioned in the other answer, dereferencing the iterator returned by `std::end(v)` is undefined behavior.

But you might wonder why `std::end(v)` is not equal to the last elements. Using the last element to mark the end of a container would work for every case, except if the container is empty because then you would not have any element to refer to. Due to that `std::end(v)` refers to *past-the-end* (to a fictive none existing element that is behind the last element of the container).

A `std::vector` (and other std containers) have a member function to refere to the last element of the container that is called [back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back).

Alternatively, you could use the reverse iterator, and to get the beginning of the end of the container [std::rbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin)

```
std::vector<int> v = { 3, 1, 4 };
auto vi = std::rbeing(v);
std::cout << *vi << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think of `begin` and `end` is that it refers to the address as a fencepost (*address in between each object*¹) rather than the fence span (*the entire object*).

So `begin` to `end` delimits the objects in between.  From the `first` object to the `last` object, and one non-object `past`.

¹ Technically the address at the very beginning-most byte of the object.

```
begin                       end   
↓                           ↓     
|▓▓▓|▓▓▓|▓▓▓|▓▓▓|▓▓▓|▓▓▓|▓▓▓|░░░|░░░|
  ↑                       ↑   ↑ 
first                   last past
```